# How to reset one form from another(Angular4)

Tags: html, angular

So essentially I have these two forms:

```
<!-- Form for selecing class -->
<form #f="ngForm" *ngIf="selectedRace">
  <label for="class">Class</label>
  <select name="class" id="class" [(ngModel)]="selectedClass" (ngModelChange)="onSelectClass($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let class of classes | filterClassesByRace: selectedRace.raceName" [ngValue]="class" >
          {{ class.className }}
        </option>
      </select>
</form>

<!-- Form for choosing your level, sets your points in the function -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="level">Level</label>
  <select name="level" id="level" [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel" (ngModelChange)="onSelectLevel($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let level of levelSelect" [value]="level" >{{level}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when the ngModelChange is called on the first form(class) I want to reset the level form. I feel like it's really easy to do and I'm just failing to google what I want to do properly, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well as a comment, the second code snippet isn't a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple,

```
onSelectClass(event){
    this.selectedLevel="";
}
```

Comment: I knew it was simple, I totally forgot about the binding. DERP. Thank you so much!